# Writing Google chrome extension for GET query

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to write a Google chrome extension so that I can highlight text that appear on any website and perform at GET query search on another website.  It will open the query in new tab.

For example if I highlight the text  "google chrome" and right click to activate the chrome extension it will open http://example.com/index.php?q=google%20chrome in a new tab.

What the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the selected text from the tab your visiting, you would need to use [Extension Messaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to do so.

For example, lets do a simple Google Search extension, in your content script you would have something like this:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "getSelection")
      sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

Now assuming you want this to happen when you click on a [browser action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html), within your [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html), you would need to listen for the onclick event.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, function(response) {
    var selectedText = response.data;
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://google.com?q=' + selectedText});
  });
});
```

You would notice once you click on the icon (browser action), it will send a request to the content script, and once the content script receives that action, it will send the selected text back as its payload. You can then open a tab based on the selection to Google to search for the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to open a new tab, you can use [`chrome.tabs.create()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) with a URL parameter. To get selected text, trap a `mouseup` event and get the selection using `window.getSelection()`.